# DBD-mysql installed ,but still error "install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC"

Tags: perl

Install information:

> Using DBI 1.608 (for perl 5.008009 on x86_64-linux) installed in /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/x86_64-linux/auto/DBI/

error information:

> [root@datacenterETL DBD-mysql-4.020]# perl ../testConnect.pl 
>   install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9 .) at (eval 3) line 3.

Perhaps the `DBD::mysql` Perl module hasn't been fully installed, or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.

Answer (score 66):

It looks like you're using Linux. In that case, you might find it easier to install a pre-packaged version of the module.

On a Red Hat derivative try `yum install perl-DBD-mysql`; on a Debian derivative try `apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl`.

Comment: A big thank you, `yum` worked for my CentOS 5.x box.

Comment: worked also for me under ubuntu 16.04 where installing from cpan did not.  Thanks!

Comment: using debian didn't worked for me, after installation of module is there need of it to enable in apache config? or something else? restarted apache already

Comment: @vishal-mote: No need to enable it or restart Apache. But just saying it "didn't work" doesn't give me any useful information to go on. What, exactly, did you see (or not see)? It's probably worth raising this as a separate question.

Comment: could you please look once into my problem on below link, it will be really helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813743/install-drivermysql-failed-cant-locate-dbd-mysql-pm

Comment: yum worked for me in centos 7

Answer (score 13):

> Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed

...so install it.

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```

Or since you don't have internet access,

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

You'll need MySQL's development header files installed first, as per [`INSTALL`](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.023/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod)

Comment: perl Makefile.PL --mysql_config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

Comment: @user2492829, What is that?

Comment: I can't install "cpan>install DBD::mysql",because not connected in my virtual machine.This is the install command to untar file

Comment: So use the four command process described in the Synopsis of the file I linked.

Comment: No, that doesn't install anything. That just generates the `Makefile` you will use to install the module.

Comment: how to install with this makefile.?cmake?

Comment: As I mentioned, the commands are listed in the Synopsis of the file I linked. I've even added them to my answer already.

Answer (score 5):

any error related to `DBD::mysql` error has not installed fully. Please run the below code in super user permission.

```
apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl
```

Answer (score 2):

As is was not able to comment (yet), I want to add something for the Mac Users.
I hat to add the --force command to install the everything properly as i have no local mySQL installation for the tests to pass.
`/usr/bin/cpanm --force DBD::mysql` worked for me. (Mac OS 10.9.2, Perl 5.12.4)

Comment: It's ridiculous to blindly use `--force`!

Answer (score 0):

I've been tried perl -MCPAN -e shell on my mac OSX 10.8.5, but this didn't work.

I tried `sudo perl -MCPAN ...`, but didn't work too. I changed my `~.bash_profile` to include

```
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64/lib export LD_RUN_PATH 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64/lib export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

lines, and I tried `-MCPAN` again, with and without `sudo`, but this didn't work too.

I read some posts and I tried "`get Bundle::DBD::mysql`" in -MCPAN command line to download it and install with Makefile. Then, I entered the `~./cpan/build` directory and I did a Makefile, but the make command didn't work. I tried Makefile with `--testuser` and `--testpassword` that I just had been configure in mysql. I entered the site https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3932531?start=0&tstart=0&fb_source=message that is informed in README doc of `./cpan/bundle`, but I already had all command line tools of xCode installed and  didn't work for me too.

Why don't do `sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell` and to force to install `Bundle::DBD::mysql`? This worked well and I got the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error. Actually, the issue was from my perl script. I was using:

```
'DBI:mysql:host=...'
```

and when I changed it to:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:MariaDB:host=$host;database=$database_name";
```

everything worked!

First I tried installing the mysql module, as it was suggested in one of the answers:

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```

After I installed it, it still not worked. The reason in my case was that I was actually using MariaDb. While this is a fork of MySQL, is NOT exactly the same thing. So changing that in the connection string (from the .pl file itself) fixed the issue for me